# Security hole using kestrel behind IIS?

Tags: reverse-proxy, kestrel-http-server

We are running reverse proxy with IIS and Kestrel. I'm planning on installing SSL certificate on the IIS server and use HTTPS, but I'm concerned that the Kestrel is someway accessible from the outside (hence accessible in clear text). I don't think it is, but couldn't find any documentation for it.